# Which time series database to use for persistent and accurate historical data

Tags: database, time-series, influxdb, prometheus, graphite

We need to store and read exact counter data (integers) over many years basically just with time filtering. Historical imports into the database will be necessary as well and the data is available in fixed time windows (every minute / hour).

It seems that [Prometheus, for instance, is *not* a good fit because they don't ensure 100% accuracy](https://github.com/prometheus/docs/blob/master/content/docs/introduction/overview.md#when-does-it-not-fit). There are so many listings and comparisons but this is often not even mentioned although it is definitely an important detail.

So the question is: which modern database would be a good fit for such data?

The amount of possible TS databases seems to be endless. Would one or more of [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/), [Druid](http://druid.io/), [Riak TS](http://basho.com/products/riak-ts/), [graphite](https://graphiteapp.org/), [OpenTSDB](http://opentsdb.net/) or [timely](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/timely) be suitable? Or maybe some other candidate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need some ACID-compliant database. For example TimescaleDB.

Comment: Do you know any other Open Source Time Series database that's ACID compliant?